# How do I create a dictionary that has the filename as key and the first character of the lines( in the file ) as values?

Tags: python, file, dictionary

So i have some txt files which contain data/lines. For instance a file Q127.txt would contain:

```
    0 45 67 78 91
    0 56 78 89 01
    5 56 43 56 67
```

i want to just read the first character of each line in  a file. Which I achieved by:

```
    file = open("Q127.txt","r")
    for line in file.readlines():
        print(line[0]) # just printing to show what i get

    output: 0
            0
            5
```

Now since i have many such .txt files, i want to read them all from one folder and store the filename( as key) and the line[0] values ( as value) in a dictionary called classes. So classes should be something like

```
     classes={"Q127.txt": [0,0,5], "Q128.txt": [5,8,0,1,1,1,1],..........}
```

How do I achieve this?
Edit: This is what I tried but im still not getting the desired output

```
    import os
    file = open("Q127.txt","r")
    classes={}
    l=[]
    for line in file.readlines():
        l.append(line[0])
        classes[file]=[l]
    classes # to see the output

    output:
    {<_io.TextIOWrapper 
    name='Q127.txt' mode='r' 
    encoding='cp1252'>: [['0','0']]}
```

Comment: What have you attempted to achieve the said behavior, and what question do you have in implementing your attempted solutions?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question on what I tried.

Comment: move classes[file]=[l] outside of for loop please

Comment: Also, you can not use file as a key, it is having fileobject and not just the file name. use this as classess_dict[file.name] = values

Comment: You want to set the file name i.e. a string as the dictionary key. But in the line `classes[file]=[l]`, you are setting the corresponding file object as the key. Change it to
`classes[file.name]=[l]` and move this line outside of the loop as it is trivial inside there

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to maintain this dictionary.

1. If you want to run this script for every single file again and again.Then you need to create the dict and save this into database. And when next time when you read another file , you need to first fetch dict from DB, update it and save it back.
   OR
2. you have to run this as one script (read all files in one script), create an empty dict in the begining and inside the for loop, pass the values as a list. i.e

   classess_dict = {}

   //in for loop:

   classes_dict[file_name]=[values]

Comment: I tried this but im getting the same output as i have in question

Comment: check comments on your questions, you are using file object as the key. you need to change this.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your files in a variable,

```
file_list= ['test.txt'] # you can use the os.listdir() to obtain the list 
                           of  files and location
classes= {}
for i in file_list:
    content= open(i).readline()# reads only first line
    classes[i]= content.split(' ')[0]
```

Comment: I want to read  only the first character of all lines in the file. Not just the first line

Answer (score 0):

Is the first character always  a number? Then you can use `int(line[0])` to evaluate the first character as a number, and also, you can access the `file.name` member to use as the dictionary key for that line:

```
    import os
    file = open("Q127.txt","r")
    classes={}
    l=[]
    for line in file.readlines():
        l.append(int(line[0]))
    # move the classes dictionary assignment out of the for loop, l already a list, no need to put brackets around it
    classes[file.name]=l
    classes # to see the output
```