# How do I make a dictionary out of filenames as key and lines in the file as list?

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary

I have a bunch of .txt files in a folder. The text files look like

```
0 45 67 78 56
1 56 45 35 45
5 56 66 34 21
```

I want only the first character of each line (for instance here I want `0`, `1`, and `5` and store them in a list like `[0,1,5]`). Now I want to store these lists along with the filename as a key-value pair in a dictionary named classes. classes should look like:

```
classes={'Q.txt'=[0,1,1,9],
         'T.txt'=[0,1],
         ...}
```

Code:

```
path = "C:/....../" # path to the folder
l=[]#empty list to store
classes={} # my dictionary
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
     with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename), 'r') as f: # open in readonly mode
         for line in f.readlines():
             l.append(int(line[0]))
     classes[filename.split(os.sep)[1][:-4]]=l
```

Now what I'm getting is :

```
classses={'Q.txt': [0,0,1,1,9,0,1,............],
          'T.txt': [0,0,1,1,9,0,1,............],
          ...}
```

meaning it is appending the entire list of all the characters in all the files when I just want dictionary to contain the list corresponding to the respective filename. How do I fix this?

Comment: Because you *keep re-using the same list, the one you refer to with variable `l`*.

Comment: I understand but how do I fix This?

Comment: As an aside, there's pretty much never a good reason to use `f.readlines`, you can just do `for line in f: ...` since file objects are iterators over the lines in the file already.

Comment: ... create *a new list*, so right below `for filename in glob(): ...` do `l = []`

Comment: Is this some school question? :) Exact same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66328315/how-do-i-create-a-dictionary-that-has-the-filename-as-key-and-the-first-characte/

Comment: Actually, exact same poster as well, @nandi1596

Comment: Thanks! That worked @ juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @kamion i couldnt delete the previous question because i didnt get the answer i wanted from there ( because i didnt ask the question properly, my fault) So I asked again. And It worked! and no its not a school project :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you need to do is to reset `l` at the start of the loop. You can use `os.path.basename` to get the filename from the full path.

```
    path = "C:/....../" # path to the folder
    classes={} # my dictionary
    for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
        l=[]#empty list to store
        with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename), 'r') as f: # open in readonly mode
            for line in f:
                l.append(int(line[0]))
        classes[os.path.basename(filename)]=l
```